# Add Meta posts about main site posts to linked questions sidebar

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions, sidebar

I was thinking that it may be worthwhile to add Meta posts that are about a post on the main site to the linked questions sidebar for the main post.

It could serve as a less invasive way to alert users to meta discussions about posts on the main site, rather than someone needing to add a comment beneath the post being discussed, the link would just show up in the sidebar.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd probably miss the link, but it's a good idea.  Maybe meta linked question can be a different color.

Comment: Well, the comment is actually for getting them to notice, and as davidism says, such a *quiet change* will be missed by most. That's true *even if they happen to look at their post again*.

Comment: Such a feature could very well increase [the Meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect), which may not be desirable.

Comment: This could be an issue for when their post is being talked about less favourably, they might feel like arguing their point on meta even if that's not the goal of the post on meta. With a manual comment notifying them, they get a message in their inbox and it only happens if someone specifically thinks the user should be informed.

Comment: @PM2Ring: How could it increase the Meta effect, when it only bring meta viewers **who have already viewed the question on the main site**?  I suppose in some cases the small amount of additional meta traffic could be the different between being in the meta hotlist or not?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm thinking it could act a bit like the "Hot Meta Post" list - a "Warm Meta Post" list, if you will. That could actually be a good thing, since it would mean people who currently _only_ come to Meta for Hot list items will come here for the Warm posts too, and that would diffuse the focus on Hot list items a bit. But that additional traffic could also spread the Meta effect to those Warm posts. Of course, this is all speculation - there may be no significant increase in traffic.

Comment: @PM2Ring as far as I understood the OP the proposed element would be shown in the "linked question" area. That one is unique to a question and not like "Hot Meta posts" that are globally.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: Understood. However, if someone visits a post & notices that it's being talked about on Meta, they'll probably visit the linked Meta question, and what they see on Meta could change the way they vote on (& otherwise respond to) the original post. But, as I said previously, that might _not_ be a bad thing: the Meta info may lead them to make a more considered response to the OP, which would be good. But it could also cause them to adopt what they see as the Meta consensus without due consideration, and that's the undesirable side of the Meta effect.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's important to notify the OP of the question or answer, so they can have their say on the matter. The comments do work to subtly notify people about it and it does send the OP a notification, but it has the drawback that everyone else gets to see it.

Perhaps a simple notification system should be added, where the OP can get a notification in their inbox to say that the post is being discussed. Therefore it's private, like a quiet word in their ear rather than a public announcement in front of the class.

A slightly more invasive approach, would be to add a banner above the post that is **only visible to OP**, something like:

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="question-status question-originals-of-duplicate">
    <p>This post is being discussed on meta:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" dir="ltr">Is this question on topic when it references x?</a>
                <span class="question-originals-answer-count">
                this is only visible to you, the original poster</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On the meta effect side of things, I think it would probably be worthwhile adding a banner for anyone that visits the post via the meta link to avoid overly negative and unhelpful reactions. Something like:

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="question-status question-originals-of-duplicate">
    <p>You have visited this post from a discussion on meta:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" dir="ltr">Is this question on topic when it references x?</a>
                <span class="question-originals-answer-count">
                </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>Please avoid voting without good reasons and try to offer help and assistance if necessary.</p>
</div>
```

*Probably a feature request of it's own this bit.*

Comment: On the other hand, sometimes announcing it globally can avoid pointless comments on the main site question/answer...

Comment: @MatthieuM. that's true I agree, but it hinges on _sometimes_

Answer (score 7):

I'd rather had an **automated comment** below the relevant post.

That way everyone who wants to interact with said post will see it, because this is the place where I would look at first.

Whenever I come across a post where I think that interaction with the OP is required I look at the comments, so if there is a comment saying "this is discussed on meta" I can go there.

This also is an automatic notification for the OP (since a comment was posted on their post).

So that way we would have

1. There can't be an OP who is not aware that a meta discussion about their post is going on.
2. All other visitors to the question receive the information at the place they are used to.
3. Nobody can forget to notify the OP on the comments.